# solving natural logarithm exponential equation

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

Can you please help to solve manually this equation to find a? I guess I will need to try to separate the members somehow, and maybe I'm forgetting some ln properties.

$2e^{a \over 3} - e^a  = 1$

Thank you in advance

Comment: Define $x=e^{a/3} $ and you'll find this is really a cubic polynomial. Apply the rational roots test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we set $e^{a/3}=z\to e^a=z^3$

the equation becomes

$2z-z^3=1\to z^3-2z+1=0$

$z=1$ is a solution so $z^3-2z+1$ is divisible by $(z-1)$ and we can factor

$(z-1) \left(z^2+z-1\right)=0$ which has solutions

$$z_1=1;\;\;z_2= \frac{1}{2} \left(-1-\sqrt{5}\right);\;z_3= \frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{5}-1\right)$$

reset $z=e^{a/3}$

we have $e^{a/3}=1\to a/3=0\to a=0$

then $e^{a/3}=\dfrac{1}{2} \left(-1-\sqrt{5}\right)<0$ no real solutions

finally $e^{a/3}=\dfrac{1}{2} \left(-1+\sqrt{5}\right) \to \dfrac{a}{3}=\log\left(\dfrac{1}{2} \left(-1+\sqrt{5}\right)\right) $

$a=3\log\left(\dfrac{1}{2} \left(-1+\sqrt{5}\right)\right) $

Hope this helps